# Debugging DNS resolution error

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I'm debugging a DNS resolution error for the domain `auth.otc.t-systems.com` with Cloudflare's server, but got stuck. The strange thing is that the lookup succeeds/fails depending on the machine that runs the query, but I can't figure out where the configuration differs.

The failure is always with following message: `server can't find auth.otc.t-systems.com: SERVFAIL`

`1.1.1.1` is Cloudflare's DNS.

What I've tried so far:

- Running `nslookup auth.otc.t-systems.com 1.1.1.1` on various machines:

  - It fails on my machine with work & home internet (however it succeeds with Google's DNS in both cases).
  - It fails on a colleagues machine with work internet.
  - It succeeds in a ssh session to a remote server.
- Now I would assume that there is some strange configuration on our work internet, that causes the lookup to fail. However I don't know what I should look for and I've also found some online nslookup services that fail as well:

  - Fails:
    https://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=auth.otc.t-systems.com&type=1&server=1.1.1.1&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000&go.x=21&go.y=13
  - Works: http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php

Any hints how I can further debug this?

Comment: Did you also try with `1.0.0.1` or if you have IPv6 `2606:4700:4700::1111` and `2606:4700:4700::1001`, they are all CloudFlare too. Also look at https://blog.cloudflare.com/fixing-reachability-to-1-1-1-1-globally/ and its last paragraph giving ways to report the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Try using dig. Twenty years ago they tried to deprecate nslookup, but its firmly ingrained into muscle memory now and impossible to get rid of, but dig is far superior. For example.

```
dig +trace auth.otc.t-systems.com @1.1.1.1
```

Will trace the resolution fully for you, and you can see where they differ.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that about nslookup. I've now tried the dig command and strangely it returns the correct ip on my machine. I've posted the output from the command on both my machine and the local machine here https://gist.github.com/thomas88/600d367387505a13223a5270c89eedda. Whatever dig does different, my browser (Chrome on Mac) seems to be more in line with nslookup - it can't resolve the address.

Comment: There isn't any reason to expect different results between `dig` and `nslookup` for this query. However since `1.1.1.1` is an anycast address the result can differ depending on which server the query end up being served by.

Comment: Chrome, being a web client might be redirecting you. Does the http header ... curl -I <the web page youre trying to get to> reveal anything about forwarding?

Comment: What's the point of using both `+trace` and `@1.1.1.1`? Are you sure you understand how these options work together?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain I understand how these work together. The point of using @<address> would be to specify the dns servers that his client is using in the two locations. In the example given, its cloudflare's, but if another client uses a different dns server, it would be specified there. For example, where I am, the server address in resolv.conf is a company one, but I can still resolve from 1.1.1.1

Comment: @Barmar from dig documentation, in the `+trace` part: "If @server is also specified, it affects only the initial query for the root zone name servers"

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that's true. But it's not helpful for determining why resolution isn't working with that nameserver, since all the rest of the processing will bypass it. Unless you think the problem is with how it resolves the root servers.

Comment: @kasperd may I ask why do you say 1.1.1.1 is an anycast IP address? I find it belogs to Cloudflare now and it is a DNS server now.

Answer (score 4):

Network people have used for ages 1.1.1.1 as a replacement to another private address in random interfaces of switches/routers APs.  (I am myself on a location at this moment where the public facing IP adress of the hundreds of wireless APs is 1.1.1.1 )

I bet my money in the machines you are not able to talk to Cloufare's 1.1.1.1 that you have an (imtermediate) route there for such interface.

For instance, in my case, 1.1.1.1 is giving me my IP address:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i any -n host 1.1.1.1 and port 67
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
13:11:51.037186 IP 1.1.1.1.67 > 10.x.x.x.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 296
13:11:51.037250 IP 1.1.1.1.67 > 10.x.x.x.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 296
```

Comment: This is why RFC 3849 and RFC 5737 have to be rigorously enforced.

Comment: "Too low" is a tricky basis for determining anything, though. Cloudflare have a lot of PoPs. `64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=1.30 ms` is my RTT to the real thing.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Your value  *does* seem a too low delay for an external connection....but yeah, not a reliable metric.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Latency seems about right for same-city connectivity with no high-latency link involved. (Traceroute shows 4 addresses within my ISP, a Cloudflare address at an internet exchange in my city, then 1.1.1.1.)

Comment: It seems that I can reach the Cloudflare DNS, only it fails for the domain for me. I've run nslookup for `auth.otc.t-systems.com` and `serverfault.com`. Here's the result from tcpdump: https://gist.github.com/thomas88/03acc781f45c9427863b1876c75acb4d